# Expected behavior for rv certified message sender and listener example code?

Tags: c++, tibco-rv

I'm running Rendezvous on a Windows 7 PC. I ran the C++ example code provided by Tibco, implementing a simple certified message sender (cmsender.cpp) and a certified message listener (cmlistener.cpp).

In principle, it looks like the outcome of running these two programs is for the sender to send 10 messages, while the listener should receive 10 messages and explicit confirm that each message was received. However, something doesn't look right in the output:

Sender output:

```
Publishing 10 certified messages on subject cm.test.subject
Publishing message: {index=1}
Publishing message: {index=2}
Confirmed message with seqno=2
Publishing message: {index=3}
Confirmed message with seqno=3
Publishing message: {index=4}
Confirmed message with seqno=4
Publishing message: {index=5}
Confirmed message with seqno=5
Publishing message: {index=6}
Confirmed message with seqno=6
Publishing message: {index=7}
Confirmed message with seqno=7
Publishing message: {index=8}
Confirmed message with seqno=8
Publishing message: {index=9}
Confirmed message with seqno=9
Publishing message: {index=10}
Last sequence number to be confirmed = 10
Confirmed message with seqno=10
```

Listener output:

```
Listening on subject: cm.test.subject
Received message: {index=1}
status=Item not found, seqno=0
Received message: {index=2}
status=Success, seqno=2
Confirming message with seqno=2
Received message: {index=3}
status=Success, seqno=3
Confirming message with seqno=3
Received message: {index=4}
status=Success, seqno=4
Confirming message with seqno=4
Received message: {index=5}
status=Success, seqno=5
Confirming message with seqno=5
Received message: {index=6}
status=Success, seqno=6
Confirming message with seqno=6
Received message: {index=7}
status=Success, seqno=7
Confirming message with seqno=7
Received message: {index=8}
status=Success, seqno=8
Confirming message with seqno=8
Received message: {index=9}
status=Success, seqno=9
Confirming message with seqno=9
Received message: {index=10}
status=Success, seqno=10
Confirming message with seqno=10
```

Note that in the sender output, the message with seqno=1 is never confirmed. Also, in the listener output, the message with seqno=0 is not found. (I slightly modified the Tibco cmlistener.cpp example code to print out the status and seqno values, for troubleshooting purposes, but otherwise, the code is as is.)

Does anyone who's worked with this Rendezvous example code know if this is the expected behavior? Why isn't the message with seqno=1 confirmed? Why doesn't the listener ever see a message with seqno=1? Why does the message with seqno=0 result in a status of "Item not found"?